# How to receive Application ID from C2DM?

Tags: java, php, android

I have completed my application and launched in android market.Now I want to add notification. I registered in C2DM and received a mail.But I am so confused. Please anybody  tell me the procedure for receiving Registration ID from C2DM?

Comment: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest read this link, from today you are on push notification it seems